# In Python, finding roots by dichotomy: how do I write a loop to find all the roots of an equation?

Tags: python, math, equation

I am writing a function for finding the root in an equation with one variable using the dichotomy method. And here's the thing: the essence of the method is to divide a given segment of the X-axis in half, look at something (or immediately see the root, or continue), then again in half, again and again. Until we reach the margin of error. Dividing it in half at any iteration, what we pay attention to: 1) on the error; 2) on other points, namely:

- if the function in the middle of the segment is equal to zero or less than the specified error, then the root is the middle of the segment;
- otherwise, if the product of the function in the middle of the segment f(mid) and at its beginning f (a) is less than zero, then the segment takes on half the boundaries from a to mid (and mid becomes the right boundary of the segment (that is, b=mid)). Divide further until we get zero at the point mid (f(mid)=0) or the next value is less than the error. Moreover, the value of mid can become either the boundary of a or the boundary of b (depending on the sign of the product of the functions f(mid) * f(a)<0 or f(mid) * f(a)>0).
- if the product of the function in the middle of the segment f (mid) and at its beginning f (a) is greater than zero, then the segment takes on half the boundaries from mid to b. We continue the division. As in the previous paragraph, the mid value can become either the boundary of a or the boundary of b (until it reaches the root).

I'm trying to implement this in code. I find one root, but I need everything. What should I do?

```
def f(x):
    assert x!=0, 'Argument cannot be zero'
    return 1.2 - np.log(x) - 4*np.cos(2*x)

def dyhotomy(a, b, eps):
    root = None
    while abs(f(b)-f(a)) > eps:
        mid = (a+b) / 2
        if f(mid) == 0 or abs(f(mid)) < eps:
            root = mid
            break
        elif f(a)*f(mid) < 0:
            b = mid
        else:
            a = mid

    if root is None:
        print('Root not found')
    else:
        print(f'The root, according to the dichotomy method, is at the point x = {root}')
```

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for recursion

Comment: `
def rec_dyhotomy(a, b, eps):
    if abs(f(b) - f(a)) < eps:
        print('Root not found')
        return
    mid = (a+b) / 2
    if f(mid) == 0 or abs(f(mid)) < eps:
        print(f'The root, according to the dichotomy method, is at the point x  = {mid}')
    elif f(a)*f(mid) < 0:
        rec_dyhotomy(a, mid, eps)
    else:
        rec_dyhotomy(mid, b, eps)
`

Comment: can you give an example of a,b and eps values for testing?

Comment: eps = 1e-16
or dyhotomy(0.0001,200, 0.0009)

Comment: I don't see how that is generally possible with this method. When f(a) and f(b) have the same sign you'll have to look in two sub segments, and if it turns out f is possitive in that whole range, you'll end up inspecting *every* segment of size eps for that whole range! This is going to be time consuming.

Comment: On the other hand, if the sign of f(a) and f(b) is different, you may limit yourself to one sub segment based on the sign of f(mid), but that doesn't mean the other segment has no root. So you should *also* inspect *that* segment. So all in all, you will need to verify all segments of minimal size.